# How to acces the fbcache history of an especific tab from a Firefox add on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am learning how to build Firefox Add-ons using the addon-sdk (jetpack). On the initial examples there is a very clear way of accessing the tab objects for all open tabs

```
var widget = require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Mozilla website",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  onClick: listTabs
});

function listTabs() {
  var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
  for each (var tab in tabs)
    console.log(tab.url);
}
```

And from there I can add listeners and such. What I really want is to access the history of each tab and take a look of what page was before it or what page is after it (if it exists).

I have been going trough the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) and I have learned of the [BFCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache) but I have not come up with any clear way of getting the history of an specific tab. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tab` instances returned by the `tabs` module don't allow us to do such advanced stuff, so it is necessary to get access to the XUL tab object associated with the Add-on SDK tab. Ideally this would be provided to us as a property (`xultab` anyone?). Since this is not the case we have to improvise.

The `id` property of the Add-on SDK tab enables the tracking of the associated XUL tab. Once we have that, the session history of the tab is at hand.

```js
const { getTabs, getTabId, getBrowserForTab } = require('sdk/tabs/utils');
const { activeTab } = require('sdk/tabs');

function getXULTabFromId(id){
  var tabs = getTabs();
  return tabs.find(function(tab){
    return id == getTabId(tab) ? true : false;
  });
}

// Assuming the following code runs inside the onclick handler of a widget

var xultab = getXULTabFromId(activeTab.id);
var browser = getBrowserForTab(xultab);
var sessionHistory = browser.webNavigation.sessionHistory;
var count = sessionHistory.count;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
  var entry = sessionHistory.getEntryAtIndex(i, false);
  if(sessionHistory.index == i) console.log('***');
  console.log(entry.title + ' - ' + entry.URI.spec);
  if(sessionHistory.index == i) console.log('***')
}
```

Comment: This is a great post paa thanks for sharing I learned a lot here